# Different realation between dataSize and storageSize in different databases

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-replica-set, wiredtiger

I am using MongoDB 4.0 and I have 2 different databases as below:

First one with this stats

```
"collections" : 527,
"views" : 0,
"objects" : 20512406,
"avgObjSize" : 145.463036271805,
"dataSize" : 2983796858.0,
"storageSize" : 10980642816.0,
"numExtents" : 0,
"indexes" : 2335,
"indexSize" : 7409999872.0
```

and the other one with this stats

```
"collections" : 483,
"views" : 0,
"objects" : 11765584,
"avgObjSize" : 6324.48132315404,
"dataSize" : 74411216264.0,
"storageSize" : 30270824448.0,
"numExtents" : 0,
"indexes" : 1632,
"indexSize" : 939061248.0,
```

I am using WiredTiger Storage Engine and I know that it compress data and keep it on disc. My question is why in first database, `storageSize` is larger than `dataSize` but in the second on `dataSize` is larger than `storageSize`?

And one more question, why `numExtents : 0` I know that it contains `data extents` and `index extents` but why it shows `0`?

Comment: Take a look [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/dbStats/#dbStats.dataSize)

Comment: @Valijon Thank you, I already did. But I didn't get the answer.